# Floating action button Center docked problem

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout

Gridview last index text not see because of center dock.How to i fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can include `padding` on `GridView`.

```dart
GridView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24), ///modify as you need
```

More about [`GridView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html).

Comment: You can mark as answer if it solves in this case, you can check more about [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)